# Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\cdot\frac{1}{e^{\beta\sqrt{x^2+1}}+1}dx$ using contour integration with branch cuts

Tags: improper-integrals, physics, contour-integration, residue-calculus, branch-cuts

I want to calculate the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\cdot\frac{1}{e^{\beta\sqrt{x^2+1}}+1}dx$$
for $\beta>0$ with the residue theorem.
I tried to follow the steps in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2116821/keyhole-contour-with-square-root-branch-cut-on-imaginary-axis) example, using the same contour, but I couldn't get any meaningful results.

Comment: Not to be pessimistic, but there might not be any simple closed form expression for the integral. It is possible that the two integrals are different enough that the methods used to evaluate the other integral cannot be applied here.